# How to recursively archive config.xml only (with WinRAR)?

Tags: jenkins, archive, winrar

I want to archive all config.xml files recursively... but only these files. Using WinRAR.

Directory structure:

- Jobs

  - Job 1

    - config.xml
    - many other files and directories
  - Job 2

    - config.xml
    - many other files and directories
  - ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### WinRAR solution

In WinRAR simply specify the source path with *:

```
C:\Jenkins\Jobs\*\config.xml
```

[image: WinRAR Settings]

Additionally you can exclude the builds like shown. Then this backup will be extremely fast :)

### 7-Zip solution for skipping "builds" directory

```
7z a -r -xr!builds c:\Backups\Jenkins.7z D:\Jenkins\jobs\*.*
```

- -r ==> recursive
- -xr ==> exclude recursive